# how to allow to use case sensitive row ids in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

If jqGrid row ids (passed as separate id property from json data in server) are different only by case, inline edit is not started properly:

double clicking in second row puts first row in inline edit mode.
How to make jqgrid row ids case sensitive ?

Data read from server is:

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":2,"rows":[

{"id":"arvelduste_20seis","cell":[null,"arvelduste seis"]},
{"id":"Arvelduste_20seis","cell":[null,"Arvelduste seis"]}

]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems for me as a bug in Internet Explorer. In the official Document Object Model HTML standard I could found [the following](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-21069976) description about the `namedItem` method intensively used by jqGrid:

> This method retrieves a Node using a name. With [HTML 4.01] documents,
>   it first searches for a Node with a matching id attribute. If it
>   doesn't find one, it then searches for a Node with a matching name
>   attribute, but only on those elements that are allowed a name
>   attribute. With [XHTML 1.0] documents, this method only searches for
>   Nodes with a matching id attribute. This method is case insensitive in
>   HTML documents and case sensitive in XHTML documents.

So the `namedItem` method should works **case sensitive in XHTML documents**. On the other side like you can test in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/test_id.htm), which use only pure DOM without jQuery or jqGrid, the method work **case insensitive** in Internet Explorer.

The HTML code of the demo is following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230179/how-to-allow-to-use-case-sensitive-row-ids-in-jqgrid/7236985#7236985</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <table id="t">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="x"><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr id="X"><td>2</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        'use strict';
        var mytable = document.getElementById("t"),
            tr1 = mytable.rows.namedItem("x"),
            tr2 = mytable.rows.namedItem("X"),
            tr3 = document.getElementById("x"),
            tr4 = document.getElementById("X");
        alert("getElementById works " + (tr3.id === tr4.id ? "case insensitive (BUG!!!)": "case sensitive") +
              "\nnamedItem works " + (tr1.id === tr2.id ? "case insensitive (BUG!!!)": "case sensitive"));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Internet Explorer shows that `namedItem("X")` returns the row with the id="x" instead of the row having id="X". The same bug not exist in all other (non-Microsoft) web browsers where I tested it.

I can't suggest you currently no workaround. You should just organize you program so that you will not use case sensitive ids inside of tables (and with jqGrid).

**UPDATED**: Just a little more additional information.

I made an official support request to Microsoft about the described subject. Microsoft confirmed that **it was a bug in Internet Explorer**, but the bug **will be not fixed** in the current Internet Explorer versions, but **it will be *probably* fixed in IE10**. As a workaround :-) it was suggested not to use ids which distinguish only in case. So just not use the ids which can reproduce the bug. So we have at the end results as I supposed before in my previously comments.

Nevertheless, because the response confirmed that it was a bug, the request to Microsoft was for free for me (:-)).

Comment: thank you. Currently letters are not encoded in ids. Is encoding lowercase letters in ids best solution for this? Tony reply is in http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/if-rowids-differ-only-by-case-inline-edit-is-not-started-properly

Comment: @Andrus: Good idea to post bug report! Probably another official Microsoft site would be better. By the way I updated the code of the demo to make the bug more clear seen. In general IE interpret the document as case sensitive and `getElementById` works also correct. The bug exist really only in `namedItem`.

Comment: I sent you Tony reply where Tony wrote that it cannot reproduce it in Linux in Chrome and FireFox. So it looks like this exists only in windows and Chrome,FireFox javascript works differently in Windows and Linux. Different Win/Linux behaviour is **very** strange, I cant believe this. I'm not member of IE or other better forums. It is possible to post it to msdn bug report also and vote/comment there for this issue. I fixed by application to encode lower case characters also so this issue is fixed for me.

Comment: @Andrus: I wrote that it is **Internet Explorer bug**. I wrote additionally "The same bug **not exist in all other (non-Microsoft) web browsers** where I tested it." So I already tested the problem in different browsers. You don't need to try to reproduce in in other environment or other browsers. It is IE bug in `namedItem` implementation. I has MSDN subscription since years and be Microsoft partner. So I will post the bug report later through one of the ways.

Comment: I'm sorry, I skipped **not** in your answer. msdn feeback account can created and unhidden bug can reported, examined, voted by anyone there. Maybe there is some IE setting which makes it more XHTML compatible. Or we can do global find/replace in jqGrid source to replace it with getElementById(), no idea why this strange fallback to name search is used.

Comment: @Andrus: Not a problem. I will report the bug, but I don't wain for a quick solution. My old experience was that after 1-2 week I will receive the conformation that it is a bug, but we will not receive no workaround. Only at the time as I was at Redmond and described the bugs to the main program manager all the reported bugs were immediately fixed, but at the time the product was still in beta stage and fixing was more easy. So my suggestion to you: use low case ids only.

Comment: @Andrus: I received response to my support request to Microsoft more quickly as I thought. See "UPDATED" part of my answer.

Comment: thank you very much for your great jqGrid support. You are genious.

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! It's just my habit to bring the thing which I started to the end. By the way with respect if small changes in the code of `setSelection` method of jqGrid one can implement a workaround, but I am not sure that Tony will include such changed in the main code of jqGrid. One should just use `document.getElementById` *in some places* instead of `namedItem`. You can try with http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.1.2/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.idCase.js instead of original `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`