# How to remove extra column value from jqgrid json data

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free Jqgrid has actions column. colmodel:

```
{"hidden":false,"label":"","name":"_actions","width":72
,"align":"left","template":"actions","fixed":false,"resizable":true,
  "formatoptions":{"editbutton":true,"delbutton":true,"delOptions":{"url":"Delete" }}},

{"label":"Nimetus","name":"Nimi","index":"Nimi","editoptions":{"maxlength":80,"size":80 }
```

It is populated from remote json data like

```
{"total":1,
 "page":1,
  "rows":[{"id":"2ARVELDUSARV", "cell":[null,"2ARVELDUSARV"]},
          {"id":"ACME","cell":[null,"ACME"]},
          {"id":"KAKSKOERA","cell":[null,"KAKSKOERA"]}
 ]
}
```

In cell array first column is not used.
If this column is removed, jqgrid does not render data correctly since this column presence is required as placeholder for actions column.
How to fix this so that jqgrid will accept data without first column:

```
{"total":1,
 "page":1,
  "rows":[{"id":"2ARVELDUSARV", "cell":[null,"2ARVELDUSARV"]},
          {"id":"ACME","cell":["ACME"]},
          {"id":"KAKSKOERA","cell":["KAKSKOERA"]}
 ]
}
```

**Update**

I looked for data format change as recommended in answer.
jqgrid data is created from sql select statement in ASP.NET MVC4 using code below. Web API serializes this to format for json for jqgrid automatically.

How to create result which can serialized to propertyname: value format recommended in answer ?

```
  object GetDataForJqGrid() {
        IDbConnection conn;
        using (var dataReader = DataAccessBase.ExecuteReader(sql.ToString(), out conn,
               CommandBehavior.CloseConnection | CommandBehavior.SingleResult,
               sql.GetParameters.ToArray()))
        {
            var rowList = new List<GridRow>();
            var pkeys = DatabasePrimaryKey();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                var pkv = new List<object>();
                int offset = 1; // required for actions column
                var row = new GridRow
                {
                    id = IdHelper.EncodeId(pkv),
                    cell = new object[dataReader.FieldCount + offset + imageCount]
                };
                for (int j = 0; j < dataReader.FieldCount; j++)
                   row.cell[offset + j] = dataReader.GetValue(j);
                rowList.Add(row);
            }

            return new
            {
                total = rowList.Count() < rows ? page : page + 1,                                  page, 
          rows = rowList
            };
}

public class GridRow
{
    public string id;
    public object[] cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way would be to chanege the format of data returned from the server to use `repeatitems: false` style of the data. I mean the usage of

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "rows": [
        { "id": "2ARVELDUSARV", "Nimi": "2ARVELDUSARV" },
        { "id": "ACME", "Nimi": "ACME" },
        { "id": "KAKSKOERA", "Nimi": "KAKSKOERA"}
    ]
}
```

or, after adding `key: true` to the definition of the column `Nimi`

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "rows": [
        { "Nimi": "2ARVELDUSARV" },
        { "Nimi": "ACME" },
        { "Nimi": "KAKSKOERA"}
    ]
}
```

instead of

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "rows": [{
        "id": "2ARVELDUSARV",
        "cell": ["2ARVELDUSARV"]
    }, {
        "id": "ACME",
        "cell": ["ACME"]
    }, {
        "id": "KAKSKOERA",
        "cell": ["KAKSKOERA"]
    }]
}
```

Alternatively one can use `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }` event with your current format of data and add jsonmap: "cell.0" property to, which means getting the first element (index 0) from the array `cell`:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "json",
    url: "andrus.json",
    colModel: [
        { label: "", name: "_actions", template: "actions" },
        { label: "Nimetus", name: "Nimi", jsonmap: "cell.0" }
    ],
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }
});
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/Andrus-.htm).

I personally would recommend you don't use your original format (`cell` with array of values) and use just the named property with additional `id` property (if `id` value is not included in the item already). If you would do use the solution with `jsonmap` you should be carefully with changing the order of the columns (using `remapColumns`) and later reloading of data. You could required to update `jsonmap` values after the changing the column order. Thus I repeat that I recommend you to change format of data returned from the server.

**UPDATED**: The Updated part of your question formulate **absolutely new question** which have no relation with jqGrid. It's pure C# problem. Nevertheless I try to answer, because I use C# too.

What you can do with minimal changes of your code is the following: You should add `using System.Dynamic;` and `using System.Linq;` first of all. Then you should replace the code inside of `using (...) {...}` to about the following

```
var rowList = new List<dynamic>();
while (dataReader.Read()) {
    var row = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
    for (int j = 0; j < dataReader.FieldCount; j++) {
        if (!dataReader.IsDBNull(j)) {
            row.Add(dataReader.GetName(j), dataReader.GetValue(j));
        }
    }
    rowList.Add(row);
}
```

Serializing of `rowList` will produce the names properties. If you know the primary key of the data, then you can add `id` property with the corresponding value in the same way (using `row.Add("id", IdHelper.EncodeId(pkv))`). I don't included the part because the code which you posted is not full and `pkv` is currently always `new List<object>()`, which is wrong. If the data have composed key (multiple value set is unique) then you can make string concatenation of the keys using `'_'` (underscore) as the separator.

Comment: I tried to change data format but don't know how to create it so that it can properly serialized by Web API. I updated question.

Comment: It is possible to add columnNames property to json response. This contains all column names in result array. It can saved in local storage and verified before restoring state. This avoids property name duplication for every row and makes data size much smaller.

Comment: @Andrus: The **"Update"** part of your question formulate **absolutely new question**, which have no direct relation with jqGrid. It's pure C# problem. Nevertheless I try to answer it in **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Great update. I found similar solution in http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1050214/Entity-Framework-How-to-retrieve-dynamic-data

Comment: @Andrus: It's interesting! The code is really very close, but I wrote my code independent. I think that it's really native to use `ExpandoObject` in the code. By the way, the code from the comment to [the post](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1050214/Entity-Framework-How-to-retrieve-dynamic-data) looks better for me. I mean that `params DbParameter[] parameters` is better as `Dictionary<string, object> Parameters`

Comment: New data format worked. Thank you. However column state restore still causes invalid data posting if new column is added to colmodel  after state is saved.

Comment: Composite primary key may contain `_` and other similar characters as part of its value. So `_` cannot used for concatenation. How to create proper `id`  in this case?

Comment: @Andrus: There are no universal way to create proper `id`. I personally construct mostly the Queries or the results of Stored Procedures (used in `ExecuteReader`) so that they have `id` property. I construct the `id` using some unique column or composed key. In the way I'm able always to solve the problem, but the solution is on the previous step: on the step of construction `sql` parameter (see your code)

Comment: `Nimi` column can contain any values, which may differ only by case and may be empty string for one row. If `key: true` is used, will jqgrid allow such key column? Earlier this was not allowed as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170325/jqgrid-how-to-update-row-id-if-primary-key-columns-was-edited and in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230179/how-to-allow-to-use-case-sensitive-row-ids-in-jqgrid

Comment: @Andrus: It seems that we come back to an old discussion. You hold the data in the database? Which primary key you have for the data? I insert in almost every table the column IDENTITY (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)). It is the best was to have id for every item (row) of data. One will don't need to change the id in grid. Thus I never have the problem which you describe.

Comment: C# code in answer creates whole response in memory. Is it reasonable to refactor is using yield statement ? In this case data is  read only as needed

Comment: @Andrus: You can of cause use `async` in the web method and to use asynchronous versions of methods like `await dataReader.ReadAsync()` instead of `dataReader.Read()`. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34162630/315935) for more code fragments.