# What's the alternative to DataTable with ADO.NET under MVC 6?

Tags: ado.net, asp.net-core-mvc, c#-5.0

I am creating a MVC 6 project and I would rather use Classic ADO.net over Entity Framework 7. However It is saying that name space can not be found for both `DataTable` and `SqlDataAdapter`. I have a using `System.Data` and `System.Data.SqlClient` statement. It dose not show an error until I try to build the project.

I think I read somewhere that those two names spaces are not implemented in the new version. If so is there an alternative way of doing it or am I missing a dependency or using statement?

code:

```cs
public static DataTable GetLog(string appName)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("ApplicationLog");
    SqlDataAdapter da = null;

    using (SqlConnection conn = DB.GetSqlConnection())
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ApplicationLog where application_name = @appname", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("appname", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100));
        cmd.Parameters["appname"].Value = appName;


        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        int res = da.Fill(table);
    }

    return table;
}
```

my project.json

```
{
    "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-ASPDemo-b25bb1cc-00e6-401e-9f49-5b59c08a030f",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "Bestro": "1.0.0-*",
        "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
        "DataTables.AspNet.AspNet5": "2.0.0-beta2"
    },

    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.configuration": "4.0.0.0",
                "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
            }
        } 
    },

    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "publishExclude": [
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
    }
}
```

I ended up trying a lot of different components in order to try to get it complied. If there are use references please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand the problem, because I like myself to use existing STORED PROCEDUREs and dynamic SQL queries in my C# code. Creating new entity for every query of the usage of some existing entity with nullable properties for saving new query results isn't a good idea. Moreover I like to use Web API to provide the data in JSON format for the usage in the frontend written in JavaScript.

On the other side Entity Framework contains the way to execute row SQL Query and to save the results in object without usage entities. I posted in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34162630/315935) code fragments, which one could use. I remind shortly the idea.

One need to include connection string to the configuration file of your application. For example you can create `appsettings.json` with

```json
{
  "Data": {
    "MyDbConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ApplicationDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
  }
}
```

Then you create dummy context class

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
}
```

**without** any entity. You will use the `DbContext` only for holding the database connection.

Then you write `Startup.cs` which construct `Configuration` property based on the content of `"appsettings.json"`.

```cs
public class Startup
{
    // property for holding configuration
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        // save the configuration in Configuration property
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                    new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:MyDbConnectionString"]);
            });
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you have `MyDbContext` injected and one can use it in context and you can use

```cs
using (var cmd = MyDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from ApplicationLog where application_name = @appname";
    if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        cmd.Connection.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@appname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) {
        Value = appName
    });

    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    int res = da.Fill(table);
}
```

I personally prefer to use `List<dynamic>` and `ExecuteReader`/`ExecuteReaderAsync` instead of `DataTable` (see the code from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34162630/315935)), but it's not so important.

Comment: Thank you. This will get me on the right track. However I am getting an error in the startup.cs file on  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:MyDbConnectionString"]); it says DbContextOptionBuilder id defined in a assymbly thats is not referencedThank you. This will get me on the right track. However I am getting an error in the startup.cs file on  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:MyDbConnectionString"]); it says DbContextOptionBuilder id defined in a assymbly thats is not referenced

Comment: @Dblock247: You are welcome! `UseSqlServer` is defined in `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer`. You should verify that `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` and `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;` exist in `Startup.cs` and that `project.json` contains enough `"dependencies"` repated to FF7. For example: ["EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer/7.0.0-rc1-final) and ["EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Commands/7.0.0-rc1-final).

Comment: @Dblock247: I played a little and I think you should just add `using Microsoft.Data.Entity;` to  `Startup.cs`.

Comment: I'm still having trouble. I started from an empty asp.net 5 application and try to add pieces as need. I get an error even though it seems to be the same configuration as the project with mvc. I have posted a link to the project [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sicxxqdg4vpimnd/DemoProject.rar?dl=0)

Comment: @Dblock247: you should add `using Microsoft.Data.Entity;` in `Startup.cs` of `DemoProject`. The library package should contains only `using Microsoft.Data.Entity;` and its `project.json` only `"dependencies": { "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final" }, "frameworks": { "net451": { }, "dotnet5.4": { } }`. Additionally it's important **to remove references to old dependencies** `"EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8"` and `"Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel": "1.0.0-beta4"`  from `project.json` of `DemoProject`. I can successfully compile your solution after the above changes.

Comment: Thats perfect. Thank you very much I was struggling to figure out the problem.

Comment: And how about using list/enumerable as a parameter to a stored procedure / query statement?

Answer (score 2):

You should post your `project.json`.

Referencing `System.Data` and removing `dnxcore50` in `project.json` lets me compile the above code:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oleg's post was very helpful.  Looks like with the latest release the DbContext will need a constructor that takes a DbContextOptions if you're using the built-in DI.  There are a couple different flavors, but you can't just have a "dummy"  empty DbContext class anymore.

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html

Comment: please post your answer, and then the reference.