# Entity Framework 7 With Existing Database in .Net 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Hi i am having some trouble pulling data from an existing database in Using Entity Framework 7 MVC 6. (I have posted the project code [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lp2ax20cgleaxue/JenSolo.rar?dl=0)). I have set up appsettings.json with the proper connection string:

```
"Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
        "ConnectionString": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Demo;Integrated Security=True"
}
```

I have my custom context:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Two Poco classes:

```
[Table("Customers")]
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

And i am setting up the service in startup.cs

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            builder.AddUserSecrets();

            // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
            builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services.

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

            // For more details on creating database during deployment see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615859
            try
            {
                using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                    .CreateScope())
                {
                    serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()
                         .Database.Migrate();
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options => options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        // To configure external authentication please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

My users controller:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    public DatabaseContext _context { get; set; }

    public UsersController(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        using (_context)
        {
            List<User> users = _context.Users.ToList();
        }


        return View();
    }
}
```

i keep getting the following error on the List line when I navigate to the Users/index page:

$exception  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.NullReferenceException

For some reason it is not pulling the information from the database. I create it in Microsoft SQLServer 2014. And there is data in the users table. Am i missing a step or am I trying to access the data the wrong way?

Comment: try to add `[FromServices]` to the parameter `DatabaseContext`. You can use `public UsersController([FromServices] DatabaseContext context)` or just modify `public IActionResult Index()` to `public IActionResult Index([FromServices] DatabaseContext _context)` without the usage of property `_context`. I don't recommend to use `[FromServices]` attribute to the property because the feature is dropped in RC2. If you use it then you should remove the constructor, which set `_context` explicitly. Se [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34162630/315935)

Comment: Thanks for the response but that didn't work for me. I have posted a copy of my Demo project [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lp2ax20cgleaxue/JenSolo.rar?dl=0). I know you wont have the database but maybe you can see exactly where I'm going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: If I open URL `http://localhost:14487/users/index/` then I get the error `SqlException: Cannot open database "Demo" requested by the login`. I can see that the constructor `public UsersController([FromServices] DatabaseContext context)` will be successfully called before inside of `public IActionResult Index()` one have `_context` which is not null.

Comment: Hi @Oleg. I know you have helped me before with great results. I'm sorry but I'm having trouble following your explanation. Are you telling me that the code should work? If now what do i have to do to modify it so i am getting results back from the database?

Comment: Could you set breakpoints inside of `UsersController` controller and inside of `Index` of the controller? You can modify the launch URL from `http://localhost:14487/` to `http://localhost:14487/users/index/` or to open the URL directly after starting the program. Is `_context` not `null` now? If you have some error then which one? I get the error during the attempt to open the database `Demo` which I have not (no `NullReferenceException` exception!). I didn't made any modification of the program.

Comment: I tried that and the context isnt null but the users list is. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cb7g30m17xooa2i/Demo.sql?dl=0) is a copy of the same database with some data if you want to create it and text it for yourself.

Comment: After fixing some small case errors in database Views `CustomerInfo`, `UserInfo` and `VendorInfo` (the usage of `Id` instead of `id`) and changing `Username` property of `User` class to `UserName` I get the error which you described. I can see that it will be executed correct SQL select `SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[Active], [u].[Created], [u].[EmailAddress], [u].[FirstName], [u].[LastName], [u].[Password], [u].[Updated], [u].[UserName] FROM [Users] AS [u]` on the SQL server, but you get error in EF. I'm a little busy now with New Year, but I will solve the problem later and will post my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Happy New year.

Comment: Happy new year! I posted my answer, which describes how you can solve the current problems with Entity Framework. You should still create the Index View for the `Users` controller.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should change `"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final"` to `"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"` in `Bestro` project if you would generate the entity classes using `dnx ef dbcontext scaffold ...`

Comment: @Oleg Thank you I was able to get scaffolding working. Sorry to bother you with this one but for some reason the relationships are not working. When i try to access a Navigation property i get the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Im not sure what I'm dong wrong. Please help

Comment: I guess that you forgot to *fill* the navigation property by usage of `.Include`.

Comment: Thank you @Oleg for lending me your genius again.

Comment: By the way I've seen that you are the member of stackoverflow since more as 3 years, but you never used your voting right, which is *extremely important*. The main goal of stackoverflow is sharing helpful questions and answers and that *the members decide, which information is helpful and which not*. It's not enough to write 100 times "Entity Framework" to be found in Google. Google uses searching engine of stackoverflow, which sort the results based on voting count and solved flag. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: Every user with more as 15 reputation points have the right to vote up about 30 answers and questions **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). So I recommend you to vote up not only the answers on your questions, but *any information, which you found on stackoverflow*, which you find helpful or which could be helpful *for other*. In the way you helps other visitors of the page to find it.

Comment: Oh okay @Oleg. I thought that did something for your reputation. I understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem can be fixed by usage of

```
public UsersController([FromServices] DatabaseContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

instead of

```
public UsersController(DatabaseContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

It's possible to use

```
[FromServices]
public DatabaseContext _context { get; set; }
```

but one have to **remove** the constructor `public UsersController(DatabaseContext context)`. The last way is not recommended, because RC2 dropped the second way. See [the announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/115).

The above changes fixes the first problem which you have, but the database and the test data which you use produces one more problem, because `Updated` field of your `Users` and `Customers` tables contains `NULL` values. Thus you have to use

```
public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
```

The way, which I would recommend you is the usage of the commend

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold
    "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Demo;Integrated Security=True"
    EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer --outputDir ..\Bestro\Model --verbose
```

which you can execute in the same directory where the main project.json exist (in `src\JenSolo`). I wrapped parts of the command on the new line for better reading. One should place all in one line of cause. The above command will create `Users` and `Customers` classes instead of `[Table("Users")]User` and `[Table("Customers")]Customer`, but you can use the code as basis and to make all required modification later manually.

**UPDATED:** It seems to me that the following command corresponds better to generation of the scaffold classes:

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold
    "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Demo;Integrated Security=True"
    EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer --outputDir ..\Bestro\Model --verbose
    --targetProject Bestro --dataAnnotations
```

because you use Class Library Bestro in the main project JenSolo. You should execute the above command from the command line with the folder `...\src\JenSolo` as the current directory. It will create the `Model` folder in the Class Library project (Bestro). The `Model` folder will contains many `*.cs` files: one file for every database table and one additional file `DemoContext.cs`, which contains the the class `DemoContext` derived from `DbContext` (`Demo` is the name of the database, which you use). You should remove `OnConfiguring` function from `DemoContext.cs` to be able to configure the connection string via

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
   .AddSqlServer()
   .AddDbContext<DemoContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

in `ConfigureServices` of `Startup.cs` of the main project `JenSolo`.

**UPDATED:** Starting with .NET Core RC2 one should use [dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) instead of `dnx ef dbcontext scaffold`.

Comment: Thank  @Oleg you very much that seemed to fix the problem. However i am have an issue getting the Scaffolding to work. It would be nice to get that working that way i can manage my database from sqlserver and generate scaffolding as necessary.

Comment: @Dblock247: You are welcome! Do you can generate the classes from the existing database tables or not? What problem exactly you have?

Comment: I cant generate anyting. In the package console. I navigate to the root of the JenSolo directory and try the run that command and i get the following error . nx : The term 'dnx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1 + dnx ef dbcontext scaffold + ~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (dnx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @Dblock247: You should open the command prompt (cmd.exe), change the directory to your main project `JenSolo\src\JenSolo` (the directory, which contains `project.json`, which contains `"commands": {"ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"}` and `appsettings.json` with `Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString`) and to run `dnx ef dbcontext scaffold ...--outputDir ..\Bestro\Model --verbose` in the directory.

Comment: yes i tried this in the command prompt just now and it is saying that dnx is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: @Dblock247: If you correctly installed ASP.NET 5 then you have `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\dnx.exe` and the directory `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin` are included in the PATH. You can use `@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "&{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}"` and then execute `dnvm upgrade -r coreclr` and `dnvm upgrade -r clr` to install the DNX.

Comment: @Dblock247: See [the documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html).

Comment: @Dblock247: I posted **UPDATED** part in my answer which show how to use additional `--targetProject` and `--dataAnnotations` to generate scaffold classes **locates in ClassLibrary project**.