# Dependency injection of context class in constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a service that uses `ApplicationContext`. So I want to use dependency injection to have the application give me the context. So I put in in the construction

```
Private _context;

// Constructor
public Service(ApplicationContext context) {
    _context = context
}
```

The problem is when I initialize this service I have to pass it a context so that's not really dependency injection is it?

Is there a way to get the context injected without putting it in the constructors parameters?

****** EDIT *****

I'm sorry that I didn't give enough information the first time. Let me try and explain it better. I have a service which i will just call service for now. It reads the header variables in a request and return xml base on their values. I newup an instance in each different method of a controller as they may have different values for the header variables. I would like the context injected into the service instead of the controller so i can say this:

```
Service service = new Service(Request);
```

Instead of this:

```
Service service = new Service(Request, Context);
```

The reason being the service is doing all the work with the context the controller need not know anything about it. The code I have will work but it would be great if i could get this working the way i explained.

If we could still `[FromServices]` on a property. That would be the perfect solution. Unfortunately that was taken away. Which would only leave injecting the context into the constructor for either the service or the controller. In which case I would still have to pass the context as an argument to the service.

Is there a way to inject the context into the services constructor and avoid having to pass it as an argument upon creation?

There may be a more elegant solutions which I would be happy to consider.

Comment: please add more details about your code. what is ApplicationContext. what did you attempt? how did it not work? etc.

Comment: Please note that it is not good practice to use a single context instance. If you are going to remove the constructor parameter for your context then it would mean you want to use a singleton instance of ApplicationContext which may cause you trouble later on as it is not thread safe by nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dependency injection over constructor. With DI, you shouldn't initialize your service directly. You should register your *Service* and *ApplicationContext* in Startup.cs.

When you need your Service, you should inject it over constructor into a controller, and DI chain will automatically inject instance of ApplicationContext into the Service.

Of course, if you don't need your service for each method in a controller, you can initialize it into method as @Oleg wrote.

Comment: This sounds good can you give an example of how its does. I don't understand how the context will get injected into the controller Automatically.

Comment: And also how would the service get the request as well (Please see edit above)

Comment: Well, in updated case, I think that constructor of your _Service_ should accept only _ApplicationContest_. You should register your _Service_ in Startup.cs. Then you can Inject them into constructor of the Controller, and then from controller's method you can call method of your _Service_ and pass them Request.

If you need to use your _Service_ in all controllers, maybe you can move them into filter?

Comment: Okay what does move them into filter mean? I have done everything else. I have the dependency chain injecting the context. I am setting the Request through a public property on service. But I'm not sure what you mean by move them into filter.

Comment: You wrote that you service read the header variables in a request and return XML base on their values. If you need that functionality for all request in all controllers, then implement it like filter, not like controller. But just in the case that you need it.

Comment: I'm not sure what filter is. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Filters allow you to run some code before or after the action is executed. http://www.strathweb.com/2015/06/action-filters-service-filters-type-filters-asp-net-5-mvc-6/

Comment: Can you post you answare with a code snip? The question is clear.

Answer (score 2):

I your controller have for example only one method then introduction of separate constructor just for saving `ApplicationContext` have no advantage. The context will be already hold inside of the `HttpContext` and you can use `[FromServices]` attribute as the additional parameter of your controller action. See [the documentation](https://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/controllers/dependency-injection.html?highlight=fromservices#action-injection-with-fromservices). For example

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async IEnumerable<object> Get([FromServices] ApplicationContext context,
                                         MyType myMainParam)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

RC1 allows to define property with `[FromServices]` for getting the information from dependency injection, but RC2 will don't more allow this (see [the announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/115)). You can find examples of both styles in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34162630/315935).